# If the mouse move over the picture then do something? Javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put some cool effects on my website.. now I want the user to choose a topic. Now I have 4 topics and found 4 cool pictures I want them as a "picture link". For example :

```
<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [1]) }}">
    <img src="/pictures/Gaming.jpg" alt="Gaming" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
</a>

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [2]) }}">
    <img src="/pictures/Gesundheit.jpg" alt="Gesundheit" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
</a>

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [3]) }}">
    <img src="/pictures/Allgemeines.jpg" alt="Allgmeines" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
</a>

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [4]) }}">
    <img src="/pictures/Technik.jpg" alt="Technik" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
</a>
```

Now I want something like, if the user move his mouse over the picture, then the picture should get some brighter and then there should be written the name of the blog

like if I'm moving my mouse over the gaming image, then the image gets brighter and in the middle stands Gaming. Well, I'm still learning javascript/Jquery but never did something like this.

Can someone help me there?

Thanks for any help!

My try:

```
<script>
    $( ".imgClass" )
    .mouseenter(function() {
    console.log("Enter to "+$(this));
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("Leave to "+$(this));
    });
    </script>

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [1]) }}">
        <img class=".imgClass" src="/pictures/Gaming.jpg" alt="Gaming" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
    </a>
```

Comment: replace `class=".imgClass"` by `class="imgClass"` see my edit in my answer @ItzeMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) CSS solution

```
.someClass { 
  // mouse is not over div 
}
.someClass:hover {
  // mouse is over div  
}
```

2) JS solution

```
<div id="myBox" onmousemove="myMoveFunction()"></div>

<script>
function myMoveFunction() {
   document.getElementById("myBox").style.color = "blue"; //just a example
}
</script>
```

3) jQuery solution

```
<div id="myBox" onmousemove="myMoveFunction()"></div>

$( "#myBox" ).hover(function() {
   $( this ).show(); //just a example
});
```

See more functions around jQuery .hover here [api.jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Edited code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<h2 style="color: white">In welchem Themenbereich willst du einen Thread erstellen?</h2><br><br> 

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [1]) }}"> 
<img class="zoom" src="http://www.myfico.com/Images/sample_overlay.gif" alt="Gaming" style="width:280px;height:228px;"> 
</a> 

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [2]) }}"> 
<img class="zoom" src="/pictures/Gesundheit.jpg" alt="Gesundheit" style="width:280px;height:228px;"> 
</a> 

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [3]) }}"> 
<img class="zoom" src="/pictures/Allgemeines.jpg" alt="Allgmeines" style="width:280px;height:228px;"> 
</a> 

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [4]) }}"> 
<img class="zoom" src="/pictures/Technik.jpg" alt="Technik" style="width:280px;height:228px;"> 
</a> 

<script> 
$(".zoom").hover( 
function() { 
   $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.5) 
   $("#myCategory").show(); 
}, 
function() { 
   $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1) 
   $("#myCategory").hide(); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: could you show my how I can use  this with my html code? I would really like to use the JS solution or the jquery solution.. but I don't really understand this syntax.. I'm more involved with php and not JS/jQuery :)

Comment: I copied the JS solution and wrote a `id="myBox"` in the img tag but this haven't really worked

Comment: I've made this example for you (with your first link and random image). Did you mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2070/

Comment: exactly !!! this is the effect I want! the only thing I also want, is after everything gets brigher, there should be "gaming" written :) I will try this code on my other images

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/2071/  . It is without any style, so "Gaming" is placed under the image.

Comment: thats weird.. I tried you code on my images and it haven't worked.. then I used your code and copied all of it. ( with the html too, but it also haven't worked ). But I definetly have JQuery included :o

Comment: Is Jquery included rightly? Isn't it an old version of jQuery? Do you have your jquery code in "script" tags? Or can you show me your whole document? I can try to it with all of your data (without images).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107210/discussion-between-itzeme-and-jaxcze).

Answer (score 1):

Use css classes:

```
.myClass {
    width:280px;
    height:228px;
}

.myClass:hover {
    //css effects here
}
```

The `:hover` will only apply when the mouse is hovered over the element, so you can put your effect in here.

Answer (score 1):

With `Jquery` and `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` :

```
$( ".someClass" )
   .mouseenter(function() {
       console.log("Enter to "+$(this));
   })
   .mouseleave(function() {
       console.log("Leave to "+$(this));
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

EDIT try this :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [1]) }}">
    <img src="/pictures/Gaming.jpg" class="test" alt="Gaming" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
</a>

<a href="{{ action('Test\\TestController@add', [2]) }}">
    <img src="/pictures/Gesundheit.jpg" class="test" alt="Gesundheit" style="width:280px;height:228px;">
</a>

<script>
    $( ".test" )
        .mouseenter(function() {
           alert("Enter to img src "+$(this).attr("src"));
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
         alert("Leave to img src "+$(this).attr("src"));
    });
</script>
```

So when you enter on `img` `alert` display source of ``` img``idem when you leave ```img`

Or you can use : `hover`

```
$( ".someClass" ).hover(function() {
   alert("Hover on "+$(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: öhhm.. could you tell me how I can use this with my html code? cause I don't really understand this syntax :o

Comment: You can add `class` on each `img`, when you mouse enter on your img you can do some effect and when you leave you remove your effect.

Comment: I need a <script> tag outside of the jquery code right?

Comment: You can see on this link an example https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ add `class` on each `img` in `mouseneter` you can do effect when mouse is on `img` and in `mouseleave` you can remove effect, you can access at `img` with `$(this)` @ItzeMe

Comment: Yes you need `<script>` tag and you need to include `Jquery` @ItzeMe

Comment: I'm on that link and damn, thats complicated o.O I updated my question with how I tried it.. maybe it's totally crap what I tried but yeah.. please have a look at it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107211/discussion-between-itzeme-and-simon).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily without JS.

A few tips:

- add classes to the  and
- inside the  add another div with the blog name.

Start by hiding the blog name with css. When you hover the link, display the blog name. To make it more fancy, add a css3 filter on the image when you hover the link.

```
<a href="#" class="link">
  <img src="https://secure.img-shopto.net/ShopToMedia/images/shoptonews/2016/01/50531-hm.jpg" alt="gaming" class="image" />
  <div class="blog">Gaming</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  // make sure the image fits inside the .link
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

// the name of the blog
.blog {
  // hide it by default
  display: none;

  // position it above the image
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;


  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
}

// dimensions of the link
.link {
  position: relative;

  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;

  display: inline-block;
}

// when hovering the link, display .blog
.link:hover .blog {
  display: block;
}

// when hovering the link, make the image brighter
.link:hover .image {
  // http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters
  filter: contrast(1.2);
  -webkit-filter: contrast(1.2);
}
```